# Given $a\in\mathbb{R}^2\backslash X$ and $v\in\mathbb{R}^2$, $\exists\delta$ such that $t\in[0,\delta) \Rightarrow a+tv\in \mathbb{R}^2\backslash X$.

Tags: multivariable-calculus

Let $X=\{(x,y)\in\mathbb{R}^2;\;x>0 \;\text{and}\;x^2\leq y\leq2x^2\}$. Prove that for all $(a,v)\in(\mathbb{R^2}\backslash X)\times \mathbb{R}^2$ there exists $\delta>0$ such that $$0\leq t <\delta \Rightarrow a+tv\in \mathbb{R}^2\backslash X$$

This problem is in the section of differentiable functions of my book.

Thanks.

Comment: Hint: X is closed... that is, *almost* closed.

Comment: Can you give me some details?

Comment: The interesting case — and the reason this problem appears in your book, I'm sure — is $a=0$. The point is that any line through the origin continues for a while before it bumps into the set $X$. Use high school algebra, once you've drawn a picture.

Comment: @mathemagician That one fails to prove a result for about 20 min does not imply that the result is wrong.

Comment: @Did - I'm ignoring you

Comment: @mathemagician But you deleted your comment. :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> The assertion is true.

Let $a$ in $\mathbb R^2\setminus X$. If $a\ne(0,0)$, $a$ is in $\mathbb R^2\setminus Y$, where $Y=X\cup\{(0,0)\}$ is closed, hence there exists some positive $r$ such that the ball centered at $a$ with radius $r$ does not meet $Y$. Then, for every $v$ in $\mathbb R^2$, $\delta=r/(1+\|v\|)$ proves the claim.

The case when $a=(0,0)$ (which obviously motivates the whole exercise) requires a more specific approach. Note first that $X$ is included in the interior of the positive quadrant $\mathbb R_+^*\times\mathbb R_+^*$. Thus, if $v=(u,w)$ with $u\leqslant0$ or $w\leqslant0$, then every $\delta$ proves the claim since the halfline $\mathbb R_+\cdot(u,w)$ does not meet $X$.

Consider now the case $a=(0,0)$ and $v=(u,w)$ with $u\gt0$ and $w\gt0$. Let $t\gt0$, then $a+tv=(tu,tw)$ and $(tw)/(tu)^2=w/(tu^2)$ hence, if $t\lt w/(2u^2)$ then $(tw)\gt2(tu)^2$, in particular $a+tv$ is not in $X$. Thus $\delta=w/(2u^2)$ proves the claim. (Obviously, in the "interesting" case $a=(0,0)$, no positive $\delta$ works for every unit vector $v$ since every ball centered at $a$ and with positive radius meets $X$.)

Comment: In other words: follow carefully @TedShifrin's comment.